# Enumerating "real" windows and child windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a small tool in C++ that is looking for a certain child window of the main window of a Windows application (UI is written with QT, but this shouldn't affect the issue).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addOutputLine(const QString &line)
{
    ui->outputPlainTextEdit->appendPlainText(line);
}

QString QStringFromPTCHAR(TCHAR *in)
{
#ifdef UNICODE
        return QString::fromUtf16((ushort *) in);
#else
        return QString::fromLocal8Bit((char *) in);
#endif
}

BOOL CALLBACK enumerateChildWindows(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM ui)
{
    MainWindow *thisUi = (MainWindow *) ui;

    TCHAR buffer[4096];
    DWORD bufferSize;

    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    bufferSize = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]);

    GetWindowText(windowHandle, buffer, bufferSize);
    QString windowTitle = QStringFromPTCHAR(buffer);

    if (!windowTitle.isEmpty() && IsWindow(windowHandle) == TRUE && IsWindowVisible(windowHandle) == TRUE)
    {
        thisUi->addOutputLine(QString("SUB-WIN: ") + windowTitle);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK enumerateWindows(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM ui)
{
    MainWindow *thisUi = (MainWindow *) ui;

    TCHAR buffer[4096];
    DWORD bufferSize;

    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    bufferSize = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]);

    GetWindowText(windowHandle, buffer, bufferSize);
    QString windowTitle = QStringFromPTCHAR(buffer);

    if (!windowTitle.isEmpty() && IsWindow(windowHandle) == TRUE && IsWindowVisible(windowHandle) == TRUE)
    {
        thisUi->addOutputLine(QString("WIN: ") + windowTitle);

        EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, enumerateChildWindows, ui);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void MainWindow::on_enumerateWindowsPushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->outputPlainTextEdit->clear();

    EnumDesktopWindows(0, enumerateWindows, (LPARAM) this);
}
```

At the moment, I still a get a lot other UI elements in my list of child windows, like e.g. "Navigation Bar", "Address Bar", "Address Combo Control" etc. for Inter.

Is there a way to filter all them out but those, that are "real" windows, i.e. with a border, a title bar, etc.?

Comment: A rough filter would be to check [window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) flags: [`GetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) `(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE)`.

Comment: The solution is simple: Formally specify what features comprise a *"real"* window, and you have the filter expression you are asking for.

Comment: Ok, in my case the hint to look into the window style was what I needed. As I'm looking for a child window with a specific caption, the feature "has a caption" is dead on.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific (child) window, inspecting the window class is usually more robust than checking for a particular window style. And since you are most probably going to do *something* with the window you identified, [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) will provide the infrastructure for a more robust solution. This will also work Qt GUI's that do not consist of native windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit naive check is to filter out windows without a caption (and a border) using [GetWindowLong()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumerateChildWindows(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM ui)
{
    LONG styles = GetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE);

    if ((styles & WS_CHILD) == WS_CHILD && IsWindowVisible(windowHandle)
        thisUi->addOutputLine(QString("SUB-WIN: ") + windowTitle);

    return TRUE;
}
```

As I said this filter is pretty naive but you may instead check for `WS_CAPTION` (assuming windows you're looking for have a title bar). As final note: **do not ever use `IsWindow()`** function, it's incredibly dangerous and because you're enumerating windows here is also useless.